# Binding Richtextbox Firstline with text block

Tags: wpf

How can i databind TextBlock to Firstline of richtextbox?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you setup INotify or a DependencyProperty in Code.
- Set the DataContext

#### XAML

```
<FlowDocument>
    <Paragraph>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstLine}"/>
    </Paragraph> 
</FlowDocument>
```

#### CodeBehind

Constructor

```
DataContext = this;
```

#### Dependency Property

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty FirstLineProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("FirstLine", typeof(string), typeof(CLASS));

public string FirstLine
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(FirstLineProperty); }
    set { SetValue(FirstLineProperty, value); }
}
```

Comment: Can u do the same at runtime?

Comment: cant add flowdocument directly to rtb.

Comment: A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Text' property of type 'Run'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.